# Is $\min\limits_y \int_0^1 \frac{g(x,y)}{1-x} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{\min_y g(x,y)}{1-x} dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, optimization

I am looking at a problem of the form

$$\min_y \int_0^1 \frac{g(x,y)}{1-x} dx$$

where the function $g$ is such that the integral $\int_0^1 \frac{g(x,y)}{1-x} dx$ converges regardless of the value $y$. I was wondering if

$$\min_y \int_0^1 \frac{g(x,y)}{1-x} dx =  \int_0^1 \frac{\min_y g(x,y)}{1-x} dx ?$$

If so, how would one prove such an equality?

Comment: $\mathrm{argmin}_y \ g(x,y)$ may not be a constant for different $ x $

Comment: Since $1-x>0$ and constant w.r.t. $y$, we have $$\frac{\min\limits_y g(x,y)}{1-x} =\min_y \frac{g(x,y)}{1-x}$$ so your problem can be simplified to $$\min_y\int_0^1 h(x,y)\,dx = \int_0^1 \min_y h(x,y)\, dx$$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'd say that $g(x,y)=1-x$ is a "nice case" and the equality doesn't fall in that case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What about $g(x,y)=(1-x)y^2$? The equality holds, but $g$ do depends on $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equality can be broken if minimum point inside integral depends on $x$, like $g(x,y)=(y-x)^2 (1-x)$.